# Central Limit Theorem in the correlated case

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

I have $N$ random variables of Bernoulli distribution with different success probabilities, and I'm looking for an approximation of the distribution of their sum, when $N$ is big (but finite).

If the variables were independent, I could use the Central Limit Theorem and claim that their sum has a Normal distribution.

The $N$ variables are correlated, and have the same covariance for each pair of variables.

Is there a version of the Central Limit Theorem that could be applied in this case?

I know that there is a version for "Weak Dependence", but this is not the case for me as the covariance does not converge to $0$ as $N$ grows.

Comment: can you specify your set up a little more? What is the joint distribution, or what do you know about the covariance structure? And how are you normalizing the sum?  By 1/sqrt(n) or by its true standard deviation?

Comment: All I know about the each pair is that they have a constant covariance, the same for each pair, so if I create a covariance matrix I'll have a diagonal with the variance of each variable, and all other values are equal to the constant covariance.
The sum is not normalized, I'm interested at the value of the the sum, or how many Bernoulli trials succeeded.